# Update list's entity value without using loop

Tags: grails, groovy

I have a list def `userList = User.findByStatus(true)`. I have to update the status of user to false. Is there a way to update the list without using iteration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of coruse there is! `executeUpdate` is exactly what you are looking for. According to the [documentation](http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/latest/ref/Domain%20Classes/executeUpdate.html) you can update matching records.

For example:

```
User.executeUpdate("update User u set u.status = false where u.status = true")
```

Comment: You're more than welcome. The Grails documentation has some pretty good stuff in there ;)

Comment: (If this answer helped you and was a solution to your question it's recommended you accept it as a valid answer so others know it's a good answer as well)